# WooCommerce: Creating an order programmatically with a variable product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to create an order programmatically. Using `wc_create_order()` this is pretty straightforward:

```
$myProduct = new WC_Product(100);
$order = wc_create_order();
$order->add_product($myProduct, 1);
$order->calculate_totals();
```

This works as expected, and an order is created for a simple product with ID 100 for the correct amount.

However, if I try to do this with a variation, it doesn't seem to behave correctly. After much trial and error, I got it to *sort-of* work this way:

```
$membershipProduct = new WC_Product_Variable(100);
$theMemberships = $membershipProduct->get_available_variations();

$trueProduct = new WC_Product(100);

$variationsArray = array();

foreach ($theMemberships as $membership) {
    if ($membership['sku'] == $chosenVariation) {
        $variationID = $membership['variation_id'];
        $variationsArray = $membership['attributes'];
    }
}

if ($variationID) {
    $trueProduct->variation_id = $variationID;
}

$order = wc_create_order();
$order->add_product($trueProduct, 1, $variationsArray);
$order->calculate_totals();
```

However, although it does create the order with the correct product and the correct variation ID, the total for the order is always **0** (which, coincidentally, is the price of the first variation).

Originally I was trying `$order->add_product()` with the object created from `new WC_Product_Variable()`, but that resulted in no products being added to the order at all, which leads me to believe it's an issue with creating orders programmatically with variable products. However, following the WooCommerce source code for these calls, I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Is there something I'm missing, or a better way to create an order with a variable product?

Comment: I don't know the complete answer, but for sure you are missing the 3rd parameter of [`add_product(  $product, $qty = 1, $args = array() )`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/find/master#L222). You need to pass `$args = array('variation' => $something );`. I am not yet sure how that `$something` needs to be formatted.

Comment: @helgatheviking Ah, you are quite right: I _was_ passing an array as a third parameter (in the second example), but I hadn't noticed that it needed the `'variation'` key. I've added that (`$variationsArray['variation'] = $membership['attributes'];`) and now the item appears 'correctly' in the order (as in, it's the right variation of the right product), but the price is still wrong. No idea what I'm missing!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Solved it.**

Even though I could have sworn I'd tried (and failed) doing it this way, the answer was to not add the *parent* product (`$trueProduct` in the example), but to add the **variation product by *its* ID**.

This may have failed previously because, as [@helgatheviking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32542793/woocommerce-creating-an-order-programmatically-with-a-variable-product?noredirect=1#comment52948161_32542793) noted, my `$variationsArray` was formatted incorrectly according to the [source](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#174-238); I needed an array with a `['variation']` key to send the correct variation array of attributes.

In total, my working code now looks like this:

```
$membershipProduct = new WC_Product_Variable(100);
$theMemberships = $membershipProduct->get_available_variations();

$variationsArray = array();

foreach ($theMemberships as $membership) {
    if ($membership['sku'] == $chosenVariation) {
        $variationID = $membership['variation_id'];
        $variationsArray['variation'] = $membership['attributes'];
    }
}

if ($variationID) {
    $varProduct = new WC_Product_Variation($variationID);

    $order = wc_create_order();
    $order->add_product($varProduct, 1, $variationsArray);
    $order->calculate_totals();
}
```

Comment: That's cool you figured out out. I remember asking that the regular add to cart support direct addition by variation id and got shot down, so never would have thought to do this.

Comment: @helgatheviking I've actually had to do this a couple of different ways for a couple of different projects, including adding a variation directly via AJAX (similar to the way you mentioned). I need to bookmark this, or else I'm definitely going to forget how to do it next time.

Comment: This is the third time this exact answer has been useful for me. if only i could upvote your answer again.

Answer (score 1):

if you already have the variation_id you can just do this

```
$product_variation = new WC_Product_Variation($variation_id);
$order = wc_create_order();
$args=array();
foreach($product_variation->get_variation_attributes() as $attribute=>$attribute_value){
        $args['variation'][$attribute]=$attribute_value;
}
$order->add_product($product_variation, $product['quantity'], $args);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me:

```
function add_item_to_order( $order_id, $prod_id ) {

    $order      = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $_product   = wc_get_product( $prod_id ); 

    // Set values
    $item = array();
    $item['product_id']        = $_product->id;
    $item['variation_id']      = isset( $_product->variation_id ) ? $_product->variation_id : '';
    $item['variation_data']    = $item['variation_id'] ? $_product->get_variation_attributes() : '';
    $item['name']              = $_product->get_title();
    $item['tax_class']         = $_product->get_tax_class();
    $item['qty']               = 1;
    $item['line_subtotal']     = wc_format_decimal( $_product->get_price_excluding_tax() );
    $item['line_subtotal_tax'] = '';
    $item['line_total']        = wc_format_decimal( $_product->get_price_excluding_tax() );
    $item['line_tax']          = '';
    $item['type']              = 'line_item';

    // Add line item
    $item_id = wc_add_order_item( $order_id, array(
        'order_item_name'       => $item['name'],
        'order_item_type'       => 'line_item'
    ) );

    // Add line item meta
    if ( $item_id ) {
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_qty', $item['qty'] );
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_tax_class', $item['tax_class'] );
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_product_id', $item['product_id'] );
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_variation_id', $item['variation_id'] );
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_line_subtotal', $item['line_subtotal'] );
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_line_subtotal_tax', $item['line_subtotal_tax'] );
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_line_total', $item['line_total'] );
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_line_tax', $item['line_tax'] );
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_line_tax_data', array( 
                                                                    'total' => array(), 
                                                                    'subtotal' => array() ) 
                                                                 );
        // Store variation data in meta
        if ( $item['variation_data'] && is_array( $item['variation_data'] ) ) {
            foreach ( $item['variation_data'] as $key => $value ) {
                wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, str_replace( 'attribute_', '', $key ), $value );
            }
        }

    }

    $item['item_meta']       = $order->get_item_meta( $item_id );
    $item['item_meta_array'] = $order->get_item_meta_array( $item_id );
    $item                    = $order->expand_item_meta( $item );
    $order->calculate_totals();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Tyler

it gives me error that `Fatal error: Call to a member function get_title() on a non-object`.

can you please help me solve this problem?